# Doctrine EntityManager query with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Trying to calculate how many rows i have in my query without the limit. Current code:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:MyEntity')->findBy(
          ['name' => 1],
          ['id'=> 'DESC'],
          1
      );
```

I could do something like this (im sure there is a better way of doing this with entity manager):

```
count($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:RedditPost')->findBy(['name' => 1]));
```

Or i could use the `createQueryBuilder()` and use `getSingleScalarResult()` function, but i want to do it with entity manager (the first example that i showed, not sure how its called).